# PHPCS ignoring too many indentations

Tags: php, phpcs

I have updated my phpcs rules in my `phpcs.xml` to include:

```
  <rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent">
    <properties>
      <property name="indent" value="2" />
    </properties>
  </rule>
```

which works perfectly, however if I were to have:

```
function test($x) {
        $string = 'Hello';
  return $string . $x;
}
```

No error appears, but it does appear if there is no indentation. I can't figure out what seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent` sniff does not enforce exact alignment of code by default. It only enforces that there are *at least* `n` spaces or tabs before a line.

The exception to this is when it checks control structures like IF statements, FOREACH loops, or functions. It uses these structures to determine the indentation rules for the rest of the code, so it needs these to be indented to exact columns.

You can turn on exact checking of all lines by setting the `exact` sniff property to `true`. An example of how to do that can be found here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Customisable-Sniff-Properties#genericwhitespacescopeindent

Comment: While this works, it doesn't work for anonymous (closure) functions inside another function call. So,
`test(function(){ 
   $string = 'Hello';   return $string . $x; 
});`

will still be weird indentation. Is there anyway to fix it?